# Drawing integer arrays

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have many slides in beamer drawing arrays of integers like the following. However I would like all elements to have fixed size.
How do I do this in a practical way like defining a \vet{1,2,3,4} command?

[image: Example of many badly drawn arrays]

Source is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}                                                                                                                                
\newcommand{\vet}[1]{\foreach \num in {#1}{\el{\num}}}
\newcommand{\el}[1]{\fbox{#1}\hspace*{.01em}}
\newcommand{\bl}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\color{gray}}
\newcommand{\re}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Merge}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
copy value from aux & into sorted array\\
\vet{\re $1^i$,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \bl $0^j$,\bl 2,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10}  & 
\vet{\bl 0, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\ \\
\vet{\re $1^i$,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl $2^j$,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \re 1, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \re $3^i$,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl $2^j$,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \bl 2, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \re $3^i$,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\bl $4^j$,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \re 3, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\re $5^i$,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\bl $4^j$,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \bl 4, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\re $5^i$,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \re 5, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\gr 5,\re $6^i$,\gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \gr 5, \re 6,\#, \#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\gr 5,\gr $6^i$,\gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \gr 5, \gr 6, \bl 9,\bl 10}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this can also be done with Ti*k*Z.

You can add an optional argument to `integerarrays` to state a different size of the cells (default 1.5em).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% user level commands
\NewDocumentEnvironment{integerarrays}{O{1.5em}mm+b}
 {
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \dim_set:Nn \l_kees_array_width_dim { #1 }
  \kees_array_table:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vet}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \dim_compare:nT { \l_kees_array_width_dim = 0pt }
   {% we're inline
    \dim_set:Nn \l_kees_array_width_dim { 1.5em }
   }
  \keys_set:nn { kees/array } { #1 }
  \kees_array_vet:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

% keys
\keys_define:nn { kees/array }
 {
  width .dim_set:N = \l_kees_array_width_dim,
  font  .tl_set:N = \l_kees_array_font_tl,
 } 

% variables
%\dim_new:N \l_kees_array_width_dim
\seq_new:N \l_kees_array_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l_kees_array_vet_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_kees_array_vet_out_seq

% internal functions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \kees_array_table:nnn
 {
  % split the body at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_kees_array_body_seq { \\ } { #3 }
  % check for a trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_kees_array_body_seq \l__kees_array_last_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l__kees_array_last_tl
   {% there was no trailing \\, reinstate the last item
    \seq_put_right:NV \l_kees_array_body_seq \l__kees_array_last_tl
   }
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
  #1 & #2 \\[1ex]
  % use the body with a bit of backing up to hide the double rule
  \seq_use:Nn \l_kees_array_body_seq { \\[-\fboxrule] }
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kees_array_vet:n
 {
  % split the input at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_kees_array_vet_in_seq { , } { #1 }
  % make each item the argument to the boxing macro
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_kees_array_vet_out_seq \l_kees_array_vet_in_seq
   {
    \kees_array_box:n { \exp_not:n { ##1 } }
   }
  % use the sequence backing up a bit to hide the double rule
  \seq_use:Nn \l_kees_array_vet_out_seq { \hspace{-\fboxrule} }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kees_array_box:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \framebox[\l_kees_array_width_dim]
   {
    \l_kees_array_font_tl
    \rule[-0.3\l_kees_array_width_dim]{0pt}{\l_kees_array_width_dim}$#1$
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\bl}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\color{gray}}
\newcommand{\re}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{integerarrays}{copy value from aux}{into sorted array}
\vet{\re 1^i,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \bl 0^j,\bl 2,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10}  & 
\vet{\bl 0, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\re 1^i,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl 2^j,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \re 1, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \re 3^i,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl 2^j,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \bl 2, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \re 3^i,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\bl 4^j,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \re 3, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\re 5^i,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\bl 4^j,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \bl 4, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\re 5^i,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl 9^j,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \re 5, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\gr 5,\re 6^i,\gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl 9^j,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \gr 5, \re 6,\#, \#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\gr 5,\gr 6^i,\gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl 9^j,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \gr 5, \gr 6, \bl 9,\bl 10}
\end{integerarrays}

\bigskip

\begin{integerarrays}[2em]{copy value from aux}{into sorted array}
\vet{\re 1^i,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \bl 0^j,\bl 2,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10}  & 
\vet{\bl 0, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\re 1^i,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl 2^j,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \re 1, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\end{integerarrays}

\bigskip

\vet{1,2,3,4,5}

\bigskip

\vet[width=1em,font=\scriptsize]{\re 1^i,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \bl 0^j,\bl 2,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this solution. The numbers inside each box are aligned which is really awesome. However, is there a  way to use your \vet{} outsize integerarrays environment? Or do I need to define a command like:  \newcommand{\vetIn}[1]{
\begin{integerarrays}[2em]{a}{b}
\vet{#1}%
\end{integerarrays}
} ?

Comment: @MarcKees I changed a little the code. The `\vet` command now accepts an optional argument specific for inline usage, where you can set the width of the cells and also the font size to use. See the updated code.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the contents of the `\el`-command with a TikZ-node! This way you can determine a fixed minimum size.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}                                                                                                                                
\newcommand{\vet}[1]{\foreach \num in {#1}{\el{\num}}}
\newcommand{\el}[1]{\tikz{\node[font=\footnotesize, minimum size=16pt, draw]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\bl}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\color{gray}}
\newcommand{\re}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Merge}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
copy value from aux & into sorted array\\
\vet{\re $1^i$,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \bl $0^j$,\bl 2,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10}  & 
\vet{\bl 0, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\ \\
\vet{\re $1^i$,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl $2^j$,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \re 1, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \re $3^i$,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl $2^j$,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \bl 2, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \re $3^i$,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\bl $4^j$,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \re 3, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\re $5^i$,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\bl $4^j$,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \bl 4, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\re $5^i$,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \re 5, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\gr 5,\re $6^i$,\gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \gr 5, \re 6,\#, \#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\gr 5,\gr $6^i$,\gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \gr 5, \gr 6, \bl 9,\bl 10}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\vet}[1]{\foreach \num in {#1}{\el{\num}}}
\newcommand{\el}[1]{\fbox{\parbox[t][2ex][c]{1.1em}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\bl}{\color{blue}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\color{gray}}
\newcommand{\re}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Merge}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{}}
copy value from aux & into sorted array\\
\vet{\re $1^i$,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \bl $0^j$,\bl 2,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10}  &
\vet{\bl 0, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\re $1^i$,\re 3,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl $2^j$,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \re 1, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \re $3^i$,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \bl $2^j$,\bl 4,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \bl 2, \#, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \re $3^i$,\re 5,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\bl $4^j$,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \re 3, \#, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\re $5^i$,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\bl $4^j$,\bl 9,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \bl 4, \#, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\re $5^i$,\re 6, \gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \re 5, \#, \#,\#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\gr 5,\re $6^i$,\gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \gr 5, \re 6,\#, \#}\\
\vet{\gr 1, \gr 3,\gr 5,\gr $6^i$,\gr 0, \gr 2,\gr 4,\bl $9^j$,\bl 10} &
\vet{\gr 0, \gr 1, \gr 2, \gr 3, \gr 4, \gr 5, \gr 6, \bl 9,\bl 10}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```